# Why is $#ARGV 0?

Tags: perl

I've been searching through Perl resources, and I could not see where I am going wrong. I am pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, because when I assign

`my $gArgc = $#ARGV;`

but call my program `perl pkTkPtBdTkNo.pl test.txt`

`$#ARGV` is equal to 0, and I can't figure out why.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $gArgc = $#ARGV;
my $input_line;
my $bad_input;

print($gArgc);
die ("Usage pkTkPtBdTkNo.pl input-line")
    if(0 == $gArgc);

$input_line = $ARGV[0];
$bad_input = ($input_line =~ /\"\d+\D+\d*\",/);
print($bad_input);
```

Comment: `$#ARGV` is the count of the array elements so the count of @ARGV here. It is 0 as arrays start at 0 in perl. It would return -1 should you not pass any arguments into your script

Comment: Just to be pedantic, it's not the count of elements in @ARGV, but the index of the last element, which is why it's 0. You should put your answer in so it can be upvoted (after taking this into account).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `man perlintro`:

> The special variable $#array tells you the index of the last element of an array:
>   ...
>   You might be tempted to use $#array + 1 to tell you how many items there are in an array. 
>   Don't bother. As it happens, using @array where Perl expects to find a scalar value ("in 
>   scalar context") will give you the number of elements in the array:

So, if you pass 0 arguments, $#ARGV will be -1, since there are no elements in the array.  If you pass 1 argument (as in your example), $#ARGV will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

This should be always true, `$#ARGV+1 == @ARGV` as `$#ARGV` is last index of `@ARGV` array.

Answer (score 1):

The variable **$#ARGV** is the subscript of the last element of the @ARGV array, and because the array is zero-based, the number of arguments given on the command line is **$#ARGV + 1.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

@ARGV
   or die "Usage pkTkPtBdTkNo.pl input-line"

I find that avoiding the $#array_name syntax entirely improves readability greatly, 
since here perl will turn @ARGV into a scalar (with value 0) automatically.